# JsPDF repeating first page rows on every new page

Tags: javascript, arrays, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am saving a PDF using jspdf.I have javascript array. But does not understand feature of JsPDF is automatically repeating the first page rows of pdf on every page and they are overlapping.Also, last image generated on every page is getting truncated and showing only half part.Is there any way to fix the two issues. so.Attaching a screenshot of page.Thanks in advance!!!

```
function jsGeneratePDF2(){
        console.log('myImageArray105: '+myImageArray);
        doc.filename = 'Test.pdf';
        doc.page = 1;
        doc.setFontSize(10);// optional
        doc.autoTable({
            head: headRows(),
            body: bodyRows(10),
            theme: 'plain',//'grid',//'plain',
            startY: 50, 
            showHead: 'everyPage',
            styles: {overflow: 'linebreak', cellWidth: 'wrap'},
            bodyStyles :{valign: 'middle', minCellHeight: dim},
            columnStyles: {ProdInfo:{cellWidth: dim},
                           UOM:{cellWidth: dim/2},
                           Barcode:{cellWidth: dim},
                          },
            didDrawCell: function() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < gtinStrings.length; i++) {
                        doc.addImage(myImageArray[i], 'PNG', dim*3, 70+dim*i, dim*2, dim*2, i,'FAST');

                    }
                }

           });
       [![enter image description here][1]][1]
         doc.fromHTML($('#contentForPdf').html().replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, '')
                         , margins.left,    margins.top, 
                         {  
                             'width': margins.width //// max width of content on PDF
                             ,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                         },

                         //Add new page and increase page count             
                         function(bla){


                             var string = doc.output('datauristring');
                             var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + string + "'></iframe>";
                             var x = window.open();
                             x.document.open();
                             x.document.write(iframe);
                             x.document.close();


                         },margins); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this kind of issue by myself as follows. Data came from $Ajax result.

data = (77) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}];

```
$.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('yourUrl') }}",
                method :"POST",
                dataType:"json",
                data:{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                success:function(data)
                {    
                    console.log(data);

                    $.each(data, function(i, value)
                    {
                        fileName = value.Date + ' - ' + 'Sales Report';

                        var itemNew = [{ no:i+1, code:value.RepCode, rep:value.RepName, inC:value.Count, tot:value.TotalAmt }];

                        itemNew.forEach(element => {      
                            var temp = [element.no,element.code, element.rep,element.inC, element.tot];                       
                            rows.push(temp);
                        });

                    });

                    doc.autoTable(col, rows, {

                            theme: "grid",
                            tableWidth: 'auto',
                            margin: {right:30,left:30},
                            startY: 0.05*doc.internal.pageSize.height,
                            styles: {font: 'arial', fontSize: 8, cellPadding: 1, valign: 'middle', halign: 'center'}
                          });

                    doc.save(fileName+'.pdf');
                }                       
            });
```

Therefore check whether your 'jsGeneratePDF2()' function called correctly. It should call outside the loop.